# setReadPermissions() cannot be resolved

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to use the facebook sdk to include facebook authentication in my android app.
But the setReadPermissions() and handleFacebookAccessToken() cannot be resolved.
I've added everything following the doccumentation.

Please sugget me what might be the error
thanks.

Comment: You should include some code and also the error stacktrace for people to help you better.

Answer (score 5):

I try to give an answer even if I haven't many elements for helping you:

- How did you define your FBloginButton? if you used this definition:

  `private Button FBloginButton;`

  you will have that kind of error, because setReadPermission is a method supported by LoginButton class; so this is the correct definition:

  `import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
  ...
  private LoginButton FBloginButton;`
- Remeber moreover to insert in your build.gradle (Module:app) the following lines:

  `repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
  }`

I hope to be helpful to you.